# call javascript_include_tag within a rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I am building a rack middleware (to work within rails) that wants to use javascript_include_tag from within the rack middle ware.

How can I call javascript_include_tag outside of the controller/view context.

I guess even this title is a bit to detailed.  All I want to do is get the correct link to some asset from within a rack middleware.

To put it at the highest level I can:  Need to have rack middleware get the link to the sprockets generated asset for a given file.

Why?  Well I guess that is my business, but its for a gem I maintain that creates a test page that you can then use rspec/capybara to interact with assets on that page.   This allows unit testing of the assets without relying on the specific context on some layout or view.

Currently I provide this capability by having the gem dynamically create a controller, and then hacking around in the rails route.  All works fine, but it just seems like its calling out for a simple rack middle ware that will handle the test url.

Also this means I have separate code to deal with non-rails environments (i.e. Sinatra) .  It would be nice if the only dependency were sprockets and rack.

Comment: What is the actual problem that this is supposed to solve and why do you think generating HTML markup in middleware is the answer? Both `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag` have tons of dependencies on ActionView and the assets pipeline so it going to be quite difficult.

Comment: Just rendering a ERB also is also quite easy in theory `ERB.new(string).result(binding)` - the devil is in the details. You have to provide the correct context.

Comment: I simplified the question.

Comment: I can see that. But it definetly smells like a X&Y question.

Comment: I do not understand what X&Y means.  This is to build a capybara / rspec extension that sets up a test page using the assets, but not any layout, and without having to add controllers, and views.  I.e. the gem does all that for you.

Comment: An X&Y question is where you're asking about what you think the solution is (in your case middleware) instead of describing the actual problem you're trying to solve. And yes this is very much an X&Y question. A better solution is probably just to have your gem create a simple view and render it. That actually exactly what view specs do already. I don't really see how middleware would actually be useful as they are used to transform the input/output of a rack application. If you really want to go that way have at it - but I'm not convinced it makes sense.

Comment: As noted its effectly the way it works now.  Not the view part, but the controller part (which then does an inline render and no layout).  The thing I do not like about it is in order to get the route into the system so that it superceeds any other route, I have to really do a bunch of stuff at the rails router level.   Very brittle.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you're basically making something like the QUnit test page? I wouldn't do this as middleware. I would just create an engine with a route/controller/view which renders the assets of the host app. It seems like you're jumping through a lot of hoops to avoid that which is going to make it very brittle - instead of very simple.

Comment: Then the programmer has to add the engine to the routes file correct?  and only if dev mode is test?  Or is there a way to easily add the engine to the beginning of routes from within the Gem?   Otherwise unlike Qunit's zero configuration setup you have several bits that have to be done to install (require in spec_helper, and then remember to add this thing to the routes file)

Comment: You don't actually have to do anything in the `routes.rb` file of the host application. Rails will automatically mount the routes of engine. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but you still have to mount the engine in your application routes.rb file: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#hooking-into-an-application . This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Ah you're right. Can't you just write a generator if that really a problem?

Comment: I know that some of the Railties inject themselves straight into the routes like ActionStorage so it's certainly possible.

Comment: okay, thanks for that hint.  As I said I do this at the moment, but its by making what appears to be non-supported calls into Rails to get the job done.  That is what I am trying to avoid.  But perhaps I can spot a better way within the ActiveStorage code.  (You did mean ActiveStorage right?)

Comment: I added another thing that is bothering me about the current solution to the OP